# Prove that is continuous and calculate its norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $g\in \mathcal{C}([-1,1])$ and let $T:\mathcal{C}([-1,1])\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ linear given by $$T(f)=\int_{-1}^{1} {f(t)g(t)dt}$$ Prove that $T$ is continuous and calculate the norm of $T$.

First of all, $T$ is well defined, since if $ f,g\in\mathcal{C}([-1,1])$ then the product $fg\in\mathcal{C}([-1,1])$, thus $fg$ is integrable and the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)g(t)dt\;$ exists.

Recall $||T||=\sup_{||f||_{\infty}=1}\;||T(f)||=\inf\{c>0 : ||T(f)||\leq c||f||_\infty\}$.

Let's see that is continuous: $$|\int_{-1}^{1} {f(t)g(t)dt}|\leq \int_{-1}^{1} {|f(t)|\;|g(t)|dt}\leq ||f||_\infty \int_{-1}^{1} |g(t)|dt$$ Since $g$ is continous, $g$ is integrable and the intlegral of $g$ exists and is a real number. Calling that numer $M$, by definition of $||T(f)||$ we have that $||T(f)||\leq M||f||_{\infty}$. Hence, $T(f)$ is continuous.

Let's compute the norm. For this part a hint is given: do it for $g$ positive first.

So assume $g(t)\geq 0\; \forall t\in [-1,1]$.
We are going to reduce the notation from $\sup_{f\neq 0}$ to just $\sup$. So: \begin{align}&||T||=\sup \frac{|T(f)|}{||f||_\infty} \\&=\sup\frac{|\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)g(t)dt|}{||f||_{\infty}}\\&\leq \frac{\int_{-1}^{1} {|f(t)|\;|g(t)|dt}}{||f||_{\infty}}\\&\leq \frac{|f(t)||_{\infty}\int_{-1}^{1} {\;|g(t)|dt}}{||f||_{\infty}}\\&=\int_{-1}^{1} {\;|g(t)|dt}\\&=\int_{-1}^{1} \;g(t)dt\ \quad \text{since} \space g\geq 0 \end{align}

Now, let $f_0(t)=1\;\forall t\in[-1,1]$. Then $f\in\mathcal{C}([-1,1])$ and $||f_0||=1$. Thus:

\begin{align}&||T||=\sup\frac{|T(f)|}{||f||_{\infty}}\\&\geq\frac{|T(f_0)|}{||f_0||_\infty}\\&=|T(f_0)|\\&=|\int_{-1}^{1} f_0(t)g(t)dt|\\&=|\int_{-1}^{1}g(t)dt|\\&=\int_{-1}^{1} g(t)dt \quad \text{since}\space g\geq 0\\ \end{align}

To sum up, if $g\geq 0$ we have that $\displaystyle||T||=\int_{-1}^{1} {\;g(t)}dt$. How can I prove it for any $g$? The first part suggests $\displaystyle||T||\leq\int_{-1}^{1} {\;|g(t)|dt}$. How can I prove the other inequality?